# various memory errors, python

Tags: python, memory

I am using Python, but recently I am running a lot into the memory errors.

One is related to saving the plots in .png format. As soon as I try to save them in .pdf format I don't have this problem anymore. How can I still use .png for multiple files?

Secondly I am reading quite big data files, and after a while, I run out of memory. I try closing them each time but perhaps there is still something opened left. Is there a way to close all the the opened files in Python without having handlers to them?

And finally, Python should release all the unused variables, but I think it's not doing so. If I run just one function I have no problem, but if I run two unrelated functions in the row (after finishing the first and before going to the second, in my understanding, all the variables should be released), during the second one, I run yet again into the memory error problem. Therefore I believe, the variables are not released after the first run. How can I force Python to release all of them (I don't want to use del, because there are loads of variables and I don't want to specify every single one of them).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Looking at code would probably bring more clearance. You can also try doing `import gc; gc.collect()` after the function call in order to be sure that all garbage is collected.

Comment: But note that garbage collected *does not* imply that the memory will be returned to the OS (as far as I'm aware).  It only means that python has the freedom to reuse that memory for new variables, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Secondly I am reading quite big data files, and after a while, I run out of memory. I try closing them each time but perhaps there is still something opened left. Is there a way to close all the the opened files in Python without having handlers to them?

If you use `with open(myfile1) as f1: ...`, you don't need to worry about closing files or about accidentally leaving files opened.

See [**here**](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) for a good explanation.

As for the other questions, I agree with alex_jordan that it would help if you showed some of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at code would probably bring more clearance.

You can also try doing

```
import gc
f() #function that eats lots of memory while executing
gc.collect()
```

This will call the garbage collector and you will be sure that all abandoned objects are deleted. If that doesn't solve the problem, take a look at objgraph library http://mg.pov.lt/objgraph/objgraph.html in order to detect who leaks the memory or to find the places where you've forgotten to remove reference to a memory consuming object.